# Chrome DevTools 100% CPU

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools

I have Google Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 on Lubuntu 13.04, and since a couple of weeks, suddenly the dev tools eats up **all** the CPU to 100% even doing nothing..
I mean really nothing, like
open chrome with a default tab
open dev tools -> CPU 100%
close dev tools -> CPU 1%
Do someone know something that could help understanding?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Strange, i've been struggling for days, and i found the solution right after asking here..
some days ago looking inside DevTools Settings -> Workspace i set a local folder.
now i have unset it and the CPU issue vanished!
good!
but can someone explain me what happened?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/settings#workspace This feature does look pretty cool actually (even if it doesn't look like it's very well implemented).

Comment: Got same issue. Your solution saved my (mac) life

Comment: Oh man, this is what happened to me, I was trying to locally edit a script and added a folder on accident. Thank you so much.

Comment: I removed my folder from my workspace and it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I removed workspace mapping to local folder but as soon as I hit a break point the CPU utilization goes to 100%.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my life!

Comment: I can't believe it!! It's worked for me too!! Absolutely amazing, the activity monitor  is not showing a 60% CPU usage anymore; it's been reduced considerably.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (100% cpu utilization when I hit a break point) and disabling the Chrome Workspace mapping did not resolve my issues.

I tested it in Firefox and found the same behavior.

I think the problem is caused by Flash plugin. I disabled flash plugin in Chrome and it stopped the problem. But caused another one which prevents me from actually hitting any breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have a MacPro 15in and recently I started to have those issues only when opening the DevTools, it was taking about one min for the console to respond, I tried the [Workspace folder solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276239/2580302) and it partially worked but the console was still frozen for a few seconds.

I **disabled** the Hardware acceleration: `Settings -> Advanced -> System -> Use hardware acceleration when available` and that did the trick.

**Note:**  is still frozen for about 2-5s but is a big change from the original min I started.

Comment: Same on a windows machine. Running multiple dev servers on localhost on one project/page. Console was nearly unusable. After disabled hardware acceleration I am now able to use chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It was driving me crazy. Every time I opened the tab Developer Tools was using 100% CPU and it was impossible to close unless I end the process with the task manager.

In my case I made it work restoring the default settings at Settings->Advanced->Reset settings

Answer (score 0):

I had an extension called `Stylish` after I disabled it, it got fixed

Answer (score 0):

In chrome dev tools settings under preferences tab, I clicked "restore defaults and reload", and the high cpu disappeared. For me the CPU was only like 6%, but regardless, dev tools should never need that much CPU, and it was kicking up my fans regardless, so quite obnoxious